# iOS - How to get more debugging information on nil return values

Tags: ios, debugging, nsdictionary, null

In my iOS 5.1 application, I'm trying to load a JSON text file into a NSDictionary.

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stuff" ofType:@"json"];
NSDictionary *stuff = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
```

The filepath is valid, the file exists, but stuff is `nil`, which means there was a problem decoding the file (according to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfFile%3a)).

(How) Can I get more debugging information on why `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]` - or any kind of API call - returns `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said: Your file contains a JSON string. First, you have to load the string and then you have to parse it using some JSON library.

E.g.:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];  //error checking omitted
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *json = [parser objectWithString: content];
```

Comment: After reading about JSON support in iOS5, I somehow expected it to work out of the box. Actually, NSJSONSerialization might be what I want.

Comment: If it is valid JSON, and you have no need to support below iOS 5, then NSJSONSerialization will work for you.  If performance is very important, then take a look at JSONKit: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Comment: Note that JSON parsers with the best performance usually ignore parsing errors. Choose the parses most suited to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, borrrden and Sulthan!

Answer (score 4):

Read the contents as `NSData` and then use `+[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:]`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you are parsing JSON :)

Comment: This answer does a much better job of answering the question of how to debug `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile`